# unable to convert back to xml from output of xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, xmltodict, dicttoxml

I'm importing xml file into dict and further converting that dict into Json.

```
data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xmlstr,dict_constructor=dict)
json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
```

I've an application to make changes to the JSON file and import that json file into Ordered Dict. After that I need to convert ordered dict back to original xml file format.

I've already tried dicttoxml library (see: https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/), but the output format does not match the original format.

Can anyone suggest any other library or any workaround?

Comment: Could you please add some example files (the initial XML and this intermediate JSON)?

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski Sorry, dont have the code on my local system. for initial XMl and intermediate Json you can refer this link <https://www.journaldev.com/19392/python-xml-to-json-dict> 
-Thanks